# Ruby on Rails application interfacing with a Datamax barcode printer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find a standalone way to interface with a Datamax M-Class Mark2 label printer through a Ruby on Rails application. I currently have a solution that is working, which i use javascript to interface with an ActiveX object on the users machine. If at all possible i would like to accomplish this without the need for the ActiveX object.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of browser plugins like ActiveX, this it not possible in a web application run through a browser.  Web applications are sandboxed for user safety and don't have access to the user's machine for stuff like this.

If you don't like ActiveX, you could build a solution using another plugin (Java Applet, etc) but you can't do this with native web technologies.